# How to make Plotly + MathJax work in React?

Tags: reactjs, plotly, mathjax

Code: https://playcode.io/1501320

The following will render the TeX title blank:

```js
import React from 'react'

import { MathJaxContext, MathJax } from 'better-react-mathjax'
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js'

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <MathJaxContext>
      <MathJax>
        <Plot
          data={[
            {
              x: [1, 2, 3],
              y: [1, 4, 9],
              mode: 'lines+markers',
            }
          ]}
          layout={{ width: 640, height: 320, title: '\\(\\beta=\\alpha^2\\)' }}
        />
      </MathJax>
    </MathJaxContext>
  );
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/fast-reflexes/better-react-mathjax/issues/44